# Need to use 2 connection strings for query in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Am looking to do a sql query which uses 2 databases. How can I use 2 connection strings for this query as it is 2 different databases?

```
var commandText = @"insert into database1 select * from database2";

        using (SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(commandText, myConn))
            {
                myConn.Open();
                myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

Comment: I would recommend creating a Linked Server if possible.

Comment: Generally not possible. If these databases reside on same MS SQL server, then you can/should use single connection string and fully qualified table names. Moreover, you can't select * from database - you can only select * from table.

Comment: Are the databases on the same server?

Comment: the SQL you are showing is talking about *tables*, not databases...

Comment: If Both database in same server then try like this : insert into [database1].[dbo].[TableName] select * from [database2].[dbo].[TableName]

Comment: As Marc has already mentioned, your pseudo sql suggests that you want to insert _all_ tables of  database1 into database2, is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

If your both data bases in the same server instance then you don't need two connections. You are *virtually* connecting to the `server instance`. So there is no problem.

```
var commandText = @"insert into [dbname1].dbo.table1 select * from 
                   [dbname2].dbo.table1";
```

I think best way is to create a stored procedure and pass dbnames (from your configurations) to the sp as a parameters. Then, build a dynamic query to perform the insert. That way you have a better control over different database names.

If they are in two different instances or separate servers, then use [sp_addlinkedserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx) to link them and use [sp_addlinkedsrvlogin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa259581%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) to login. Also make sure to drop them after performing the action.

As a general advice, this is not recommended as its error prone. Bit more details on comments...

Comment: @MarcGravell, can you elaborate?

Comment: most I've worked with want databases to be silos; if you need to talk to 2 : fine; but talk to the 2 *separately*, so that they have liberty to move databases around without as much impact. Also: there are scenarios where each database would warrant separate accounts, etc

Comment: @MarcGravell, I agree, it could be an advice. Also if the db names are changed this will fail.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  However, if you have control over the databases, you can set them up for a cross-server select using a single connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Create a login that has access to both databases and just use a single connection string. Your query will be like:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO [Database1].[dbo].[Table] SELECT * FROM  [Database2].[dbo].[Table]
```

Comment: `[Database1].dbo.[Table]` (twice), surely... but I should emphasize for the OP - this is not good practice and most DBAs will shoot you if they catch you doing this...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't. You should execute the select statement on the first database and then the insert into the second database.